# How to check if parameters exist within an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a method that allows the user to enter 2 string parameters (author, title) and have the code check each ArrayList entry. If a book with the given parameters exists, it returns the book, if it does not exist, it should return null.

My code currently looks like:

```
public Book checkBook(String title, String author)
{
    for(Book allbooks : books)
    {
        if(allbooks == checkBook(title, author)) {
            return allbooks;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Book does not exist");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, this results in an infinite loop. I did initially have the 'return null' part within the loop, but it seems a return statement outside of the loop is required to compile.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: use `.equals` instead of `==`

Comment: It does not result in an infinite loop; what makes you think that it does?

Comment: In this case it's important to see what's the input of the method as well as how does `books` look like. Please try to provide a minimal running example which we'll be able to run and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line **if(allbooks == checkBook(title, author))** you are doing recursion by calling checkbook method again and again, in your code it will not comparing the title and author with anything. Create getter methods of title and author in Book class and do the comparison like this, it will works dine.

It should be like this:

```
public Book checkBook(String title, String author)
{
   for(Book allbooks : books)
   {
       if(allbooks.getTitle().equals(title) && allbooks.getAuthor().equals(author)) {
           return allbooks;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

And there is no any need for **else** in the code, because it will keep on printing the error message until it does not find it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks! I was not aware that you could test each parameter using .equals, awesome.

Comment: Please do upvote to the answer and mark it as satisfied answer to thank me. :)